# Not possible in C++ to retrieve the value of jlong from java context using QAndroidJniObject JNI. Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, qandroidjniobject

In the C++ context, it is not possible to retrieve the value of jlong when calling a function from the java context using the QAndroidJniObject JNI. Only the jstring value is retrieved. How to extract jlong? How can this be done? Maybe I need on JNI extern C to pass instead of QAndroidJniObject if it is possible in Qt?

```
//----------In Java context:
package com.sim.lib.operation.OperationData

public class OperationData {
    private final String mID;
    private Long mAmount;
    public String getID() {
        return this.mID;
    }
    public Long getAmount() {
        return this.mAmount;
    }
    OperationData(){
        this.mAmount = 55;
        this.mID = "someid111";
    }
}
//----------In Java context:
//other package
import com.sim.lib.operation.OperationData
public static native void approvedStatusSendToQt(java.lang.Object statusObj);
OperationData mOperationData = new OperationData();
approvedStatusSendToQt((Object)mOperationData);
//------------------------------------------------In C++ context:
void AndroidClass::registerNatives()
{
    JNINativeMethod methods[] {
        {"approvedStatusSendToQt", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V",reinterpret_cast<void *>(onOperationStatusApprovedReceived)}
    }
//.....register method
};
static void onOperationStatusApprovedReceived(JNIEnv *env, jobject /*thiz*/,jobject statusObj)
{
      QAndroidJniObject callbackObj(statusObj);
qDebug()<<"mId"<<callbackObj.callObjectMethod<jstring>("getID").toString(); //Print  "someid111" it's ok
qDebug()<<"mAmount"<< callbackObj.callMethod<jlong>("getAmount", "()J"); //Print exception  System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/sim/lib/operation/OperationData;.getAmount()J"
//qDebug()<<"mAmount"<< callbackObj.callMethod<jlong>("getAmount");//the same mistake 
}
```

Comment: isn't `Long` the boxed type that inherits from `Object`, did you mean to return a `long` instead?

Comment: The OperationData class actually has almost 70 private variables of different types, so I return jobject

Comment: ok, but if you return a `java.lang.Long` object then you need to call [`longValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue()) on it to get to the jlong compatible value right?

Comment: You are right, I am new to java and I did not pay attention to what needs to be cast here, but if I do callbackObj.callObjectMethod("getAmount", "()J").callMethod<jlong>("longValue");, then unfortunately this does not change the situation: W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/sim/lib/operation/OperationData;.getAmount()J"    W System.err: at AndroidPaymServiceUtils.approvedStatusSendToQt(Native Method)  ] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetMethodID received NULL jclass      ]     in call to GetMethodID    ]  from void approvedStatusSendToQt(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I understood what you meant, but then I will have to cast it on the java side, and this will have to re-create the class and copy the values again, since this is a class in the compiled library. It will turn out a little costly, I would like to resolve this on the C ++ side without using intermediate copies, but as I understand it, this will not work. Thank you!

Comment: _"if I do callbackObj.callObjectMethod("getAmount", "()J").callMethod<jlong>("longValue");, then unfortunately this does not change the situation: W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"_. Because that's the wrong method signature. `"()J"` means "takes no argument and returns a `long`". And as has been established you're actually returning a `Long`, so you'd need something like `"()Ljava/lang/Long;"`.

Comment: It works! Here my mistake was, thanks for your help!